# Ternary with three conditions Javascript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I have this structure

```
const name = user.name;
const email = user.email;
const doc = user.doc;
const paramsSearch = req?.params?.search;
const search = …;
```

I want to transform search in a ternary like:

```
const search = paramsSearch === user.name ? …
```

if its equal to name or email or doc then search will be one of them, else return an empty string

I have tried the if else condition but i need it in ternary

Comment: Do you really mean _“if its equal to name, email **and** doc”_ instead of _“if its equal to name, email **or** doc”_? See [Check variable equality against a list of values](/q/4728144/4642212). How is this specifically about the conditional operator?

Comment: I'm gonna change it its actually if its either equal to one of them so it would be an OR case

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Amanda I added an answer with 2 solutions. I hope that will help in your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```js
const search =
  paramsSearch === name
    ? name
    : paramsSearch === email
    ? email
    : paramsSearch === doc
    ? doc
    : "";
```

Comment: Then why use a conditional expression at all? Simply do `[ user.name, user.email, user.doc ].find(paramsSearch) ?? ""`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon How would we know which one actually matched ?

Comment: You wouldn’t know that with your approach either.

Comment: Actually the person said that he/she want it with three conditions that's why I did it like that

Comment: Is there anything wrong in it ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, We have a search value and it should be match with either `user.name`, `user.email` or `user.doc`. If it will not match then we have to assign an `empty` string in the search.

You can achieve that in different ways **:**

1. Using nested ternary operators.

```js
const paramSearch = 'alpha';
const user = {
  name: 'alpha',
  email: 'alpha@gmail.com',
  doc: 'document1',
}

const search = (paramSearch === user.name) ? user.name
    : (paramSearch === user.email) ? user.email
    : (paramSearch === user.doc) ? user.doc
    : '';
    
console.log(search);
```

2. We can achieve it by using [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method of JavaScript.

```js
const paramSearch = 'alpha';
const user = {
  name: 'alpha',
  email: 'alpha@gmail.com',
  doc: 'document1',
}

// Using Object.values() method to get the array of object values and then using Array.find() getting the matched element.
const search = Object.values(user).find(elem => elem === paramSearch) 

// Using nullish operator to assign empty string if search is undefined or null
console.log(search ?? '')
```